# Rails Net::OpenTimeout execution expired after upgrading to Ruby 2.5.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Literally one second after the update of our production app to Ruby 2.5.3 from Ruby 2.3.6 (we're on Rails 5.2.0), we started getting Net::OpenTimeout alerts in our exception monitoring platform.

We isolated the deploy of the Ruby upgrade (which was just changing the ruby version in `.ruby-version` and Gemfile) so that we could pinpoint any new issues to the ruby version change.

Ruby 2.5.3 was installed using rvm.

We use mandrill to send e-mails and their support team says everything is fine with their platform, which we believe to be true, because it would be too much of a coincidence for the exceptions start appearing in the exact second deploy finished.

We are using Sidekiq, so after the jobs fail they go to the retry queue, and eventually are re-started, when they then succeed. It's very random, but almost 70% of our mailers are now failing the first time in Sidekiq and only then being sent on the second or third attempt.

Here's our mandrill config:

```
    {
        address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
        authentication: :plain,
        user_name: 'ouruser@name.com',
        port: 2525,
        password: 'thisIsNotOurRealPassword',
        domain: 'ourdomain.com'
      }
```

**UPDATE**: the troubles have been even more catastrophic, as every single outbound connection that our app uses (like external APIs) is also timing out with Net::OpenTimeout execution expired, in a very random (but frequent) way.

The bad news is that even if we re-deploy using Ruby 2.3.6 the issues don't go away.

Comment: Does that error happens periodically or in every request? Btw, could you include the request code snippet?

Comment: @vnbrs It happens periodically, not in every request. It's actually quite random, but around 70% of the mailers are failing first before they get retried by Sidekiq then sent. About the request code, which code exactly are you talking about? It's a simple `AppNotifier.name_of_mailer.deliver_later`, nothing fancy in the mailer as well, and it was working before the upgrade from 2.3.6.